# What path should I place my bare git repositories?

Tags: git, security

Scott Chacon's *Pro Git* has really straight-forward instructions on how to setup your own git server. The only question I have is where the actual repositories ought to reside. His example shows him putting the repos under `/opt`, but if I'm going to create a git user (and thus a `git/` directory) why wouldn't I just store under `/home/git/myproject.git`, etc.? Are there some permissions, or security issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, there aren't. Put it wherever you want.**

For permissions, you need to make sure that everybody that should have permissions to use the repositories gets the permissions to do so. In your case that would mean that many persons will have access to the home directory of the git user.

Also, you may change your os at some time in the future. In this case, to keep the urls valid, you will need to put the repositories at the same path as on the old system. That can lead to problems if you put the repositories to a location like `/media/usbstick/repos`. If you change the system the path may change to `/mnt/usbstick/repos`.